# Variable in outer describe block is undefined when accessing in inner describe block with Mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I've got a test suite that looks like the below:

(Notice the `accountToPost` variable at the top (below the first `describe` block)

```
describe('Register Account', function () {

    var accountToPost;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        accountToPost = {
            name: 'John',
            email: 'email@example.com',
            password: 'password123'
        };

        done();
    });

    describe('POST /account/register', function(){

        describe('when password_confirm is different to password', function(){

            //accountToPost is undefined!
            accountToPost.password_confirm = 'something'; 

            it('returns error', function (done) {
              //do stuff & assert
            });
        });
    });
});
```

My issue is that when I try to modify `accountToPost` in my nested describe block, it's undefined...

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Keep the assignment where it is but wrap in in a `beforeEach` callback and your code will execute:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    accountToPost.password_confirm = 'something';
});
```

Mocha loads your file and executes it, which means the `describe` calls are executed right away *before* Mocha actually runs the test suite. That's how it figures out the set of tests you've declared.

I typically put nothing more than function and variable declarations in the body of the callbacks I pass to `describe`. Everything that *changes* the state of objects used in testing belongs in `before`, `beforeEach`, `after` or `afterEach`, or inside the tests themselves.

Another thing to know is that `beforeEach` and `afterEach` are executed before and after the callbacks to the `it` calls *not* the callbacks to the `describe` calls. So if you thought your `beforeEach` callback would execute before `describe('POST /account/register', ...` this is not correct. It executes just before `it('returns error', ...`.

This code should illustrate what I am talking about:

```
console.log("0");
describe('level A', function () {
    console.log("1");
    beforeEach(function () {
        console.log("5");
    });

    describe('level B', function(){
        console.log("2");

        describe('level C', function(){
        console.log("3");

            beforeEach(function () {
                console.log("6");
            });

            it('foo', function () {
                console.log("7");
            });
        });
    });
});
console.log("4");
```

If you run mocha on this code, you'll see the numbers being output to the console in increasing order. I've structured it the same way your test suite is structured, but with the addition of my recommended fix. The numbers 0 to 4 are output while Mocha is figuring out what tests are present in the suite. The testing has not begun yet. The other numbers are output during testing proper.