# before() not executing before subsequent describes()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Given the following code :

```
var api = {};
var models = {};
describe(vars.project.name, function() {

  before(function(done) {

    // Loading models
    models_module.getDbInstance('0.1', function(res) {
      db = res;

      var config = {
        server: server,
        db: db,
        v: '0.1'
      };

      // Importing all the tests 
      api.base = require('./functions/api.base.js')(config);
      models.test_table = require('./functions/models.test_table.js')(config);

      done();
    });
  });


  // Tests general status
  describe('checking the status of the API without a version', function() {
    it('should succeed with 200 OK', api.base.status.without_route);
  });
});
```

This loads the database with my models for version 0.1 and then `require` my tests definitions, passing it the database and some other config infos. This is in theory.

Instead, I get an error saying `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`. This means that it tries to execute my tests, or at least initialize it, before completing the `before` function.

I also tried with `async.series` (loading the models, then loading the tests) but it doesn't do anything, only displays `0 passing (0ms)`.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Did you check that `api.base = require('./functions/api.base.js')(config);` actually assigns a value other than `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, I just tested in the node console, line by line, and it returns an object with all my test functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the tree and missed the forest...

This cannot work:

```
describe('checking the status of the API without a version', function() {
    it('should succeed with 200 OK', api.base.status.without_route);
});
```

The problem is that you are trying to evaluate `api.base` while Mocha is **constructing** the test suite. In brief, you should keep in mind that the callbacks that are passed to `describe` are evaluated **before** the tests start. The callbacks passed to the `it` calls are not evaluated until the individual tests are executed. (See another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21470373/1906307) of mine for all the gory details of what happens when.) So at the stage where `api.base.satus.without_route` is evaluated, `api.base` has not been set.

```
describe('checking the status of the API without a version', function() {
    it('should succeed with 200 OK', function () {
        api.base.status.without_route();
    });
});
```

Given the code you had in your question, I've assumed that `api.base.status.without_route` is a function which would fail if your conditions are not met. That it be a function looks peculiar to me but I don't know the larger context of your application. I'm basing my assumption on the fact that the 2nd argument passed to `it` should be a callback. If it is not a function, then you'll need to write whatever specific test you need (`if (api.base.status.without_route === ...) etc.`)