# loop describes in mocha based on set up in before block

Tags: mocha.js

I'm trying to create tests dynamically from a decision table made in google spread like so:

```
describe "Dynamic test", ->
    rules = [1] # add a dummy element to see something in logs
    before (done) ->
        Tabletop.init(
            key: 'the google spreadsheet key'
            callback: (data, tabletop) ->
                decisionTable = createTable(data)
                rules = extractRulesFromDesicionTable(decisionTable)
                console.log 'rules created'
                done()
            simpleSheet: true)


    for rule in rules
        do (rule) ->
            describe rule.name, ->
                console.log "describing rule"
                it 'should be nice', ->
                    true.should.be.ok
```

The thing is that the `describe rule` gets logged before the `rules created`.

Is there a way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is that the describe rule gets logged before the rules created.

Yes, that's how Mocha is designed to operate. The sequence of events is:

1. Your outer `describe` is called. It immediately calls its anonymous function.
2. The `before` is called. This registers the callback passed to it for *future* execution.
3. Your `for rule in rules` loop is executed.
4. The callback you passed to `before` is executed. Note that by this time it is **too late** to call `describe` or `it`. (Mocha may accept the calls, and in some cases it may do what you want but it is undefined behavior really. If it works, it's just luck.)

The general rule is that a callback passed to `describe` is executed immediately. Callbacks passed to hooks (`before`, `beforeAll`, etc.) or tests (`it`) are executed *later*. (I have an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21470373/1906307) that goes into the details of execution order.)

I do not see a simple solution to what you want to do. You are trying to generate tests, which is not usually a problem, provided that it is done *synchronously*. (I've done it many times, for instance by using Node's synchronous `fs` calls to read a set of files.) There is no provision for doing it asynchronously. I'd expect you'd have to [use mocha programmatically](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically) to do this.

Comment: Thanks! From [use mocha programmatically](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically) it didn't look like you could pass a `--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register` parameter, so I didn't dare to use it :) But, first constructing a `rules.js` file and then running mocha reading the file synchronously works like a charm: `coffee ./test/create-dynamic-rules.coffee --nodejs && ./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./test/dynamic-test.coffee --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --timeout 15000`