# Mocha async execution order

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha for js unit tests of AMD (requirejs) modules.  Since the module needs to be loaded by requirejs, the test is asynchronous:

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var should = chai.should();
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '../../',
    paths: {
        PieWidget: 'tools/scheduler/PieWidget'
    }
});

describe('PieWidget tests', function() {
    var PieWidget, pw1, pw2;
    before('Set up the PieWidget module', function(done) {
        requirejs(['PieWidget'], function(_) {
            PieWidget = _;
            done(); // tell Mocha we are now ready to run the tests
        });
    });

    // tests here
};
```

For readability and conciseness, I want to say:

```
context('when the constructor is called', function() {
    pw1 = new PieWidget();
    it('should create a valid PieWidget', function() {
        pw1.should.exist;
        //todo check validity
    });
});
```

but Mocha runs these lines out of order.  To satisfy Mocha, I must either:

```
context('when the constructor is called', function() {
    it('should create a valid PieWidget', function() {
        pw1 = new PieWidget();
        pw1.should.exist;
        //todo check validity
    });
});
```

which to my eye is a mismatch between the description and the logic, or:

```
context('when the constructor is called', function() {
    before(function() {
        pw1 = new PieWidget();
    });
    it('should create a valid PieWidget', function() {
        pw1.should.exist;
        //todo check validity
    });
});
```

which seems verbose and less readable.  Is there a better way to write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways you've discovered works are it, as far as Mocha is concerned.

Mocha works in two phases: test discovery and test execution. (I don't think the documentation spells this out.) The callbacks passed to `describe` and `context` are called **immediately** by Mocha, during test discovery. The `before`, `beforeEach` hooks are called during test execution. (See the example with the `console.log` calls that output numbers in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21470373/1906307) to see this order in action.) You cannot have anything executed during test discovery that depends on code executed during test execution. This is principle that your code violates: `new PieWidget()` executes *before* your `before` hook.

Now, I would argue that this is the correct way to write your test:

```
context('the constructor', function() {
    it('should create a valid PieWidget', function() {
        var pw1 = new PieWidget();
        pw1.should.exist;
        //todo check validity
    });
});
```

Why? Your initial attempt did not work because Mocha does not allow it, but suppose that it does. And suppose that your constructor crashes. What is Mocha to make of this failure? I can tell you what Mocha would do. It would just not execute any test at all. If you happen to test another object in your suite, which is not impacted by the fact that `PieWidget` is buggy, those tests won't run either. Mocha will give up right away.

What about putting the creation in a `before` hook, which you've discovered works. This is still not a good idea. The end result will be different but the reason why it is a bad idea is essentially the same: Mocha won't run as many tests as it could. If your `PieWidget` is buggy, then the hook will crash. Mocha interprets a crash in a hook as a sign that the *test suite itself* is buggy and will abort execution. Any test executed before the crash is fine but any tests that would be executed after the crash won't be executed.

Doing it the way I show above ensures that when you run your test suite Mocha will run a maximal number of tests. The failure of `new PieWidget()` in your test won't have any effect whatsoever on any other test.

Comment: Thanks for the above answer.  Do you know if all of the js test frameworks behave this way?