# How does Mocha execute the 'it' calls? How to execute tests synchronously?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

Observe the following tests:

```
describe("Testing i", function(){

    var i = 0;
    it('i should be 0', function() {
        expect(i).to.equal(0);
    });

    i++;
    it('i should be 1', function() {
        expect(i).to.equal(1);
    });

    i= 7;
    it('i should be 7', function() {
        expect(i).to.equal(7);
    });
});
```

The first two tests fail. But I have no idea why! What am I doing wrong?

The test shows the following:

[image: NPM test result using Mocha]

I'm porting QUnit to Mocha and I'm looking where the asserts should go.
 
In QUnit you have Module -> Test -> Asserts. 
Is it here Describe -> Describe -> It's?

Comment: What is the error/fail output?

Comment: I'll add it as a picture.

Comment: It looks almost like the callback isn't executed directly...

Comment: I asume due to the fact that the functions can handle also asynchron code, all `it` callbacks are collected, and execute after, thats why when the first `it`function is called and `i` is set to 7. But since I couldn't find no infos in the documentation, I just post my opinion as comment. :-)

Comment: It got the same idea, but it looks super weird. Maybe it is the idea that the it should contain the tests. But I can't find any resources on the matter.

Comment: I don't think the question is a duplicate.

Comment: I agree that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: It *is* a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470349/variable-in-outer-describe-block-is-undefined-when-accessing-in-inner-describe-b), because in both cases the surprising results issue from the *same misconception* regarding the order in which Mocha executes the tests. The problem is the same, and the answer is the same.

Comment: @Louis the underlying cause may be the same, but the observed behaviour is different. The answer also doesn't apply to this question. The answers posted here fit the question much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the following is the way to go:

```
describe("Testing i", function(){

    it('i increments', function(){

        var i = 0;
        expect(i, 'i should be 0').to.equal(0);

        i++;
        expect(i, 'i should be 1').to.equal(1);

        i = 7;
        expect(i, 'i should be 7').to.equal(7);
    });

});
```

The `QUnit.module` maps to `describe`, `QUnit.test` maps to `it` and `assert` maps to `expect`.

I've written a blog on the subject: [Convert QUnit test to Mocha / Chai](https://keestalkstech.com/2016/08/convert-qunit-test-to-mocha-chai/).

Comment: Perhaps you should post what exactly it is you're trying to test (for instance, if you want to "carry" values from one test to the next, you can attach them to the `this` object, which is available for each test, or declare a variable within the `describe` block, like @winner_joiner is proposing in their answer).

Comment: I've added a series of tests. I'm porting my QUnit tests to the Mocha framework.

Comment: I whipped up some quick code [here](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/c94b51c8d302fb379f7ebde2f9401e0e). `result` is scoped to the `describe` block, which means you can "reuse" it in between tests.

Comment: You can still create separate tests for each expectation (as per [my gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/c94b51c8d302fb379f7ebde2f9401e0e), which IMO is cleaner than having a lot of expectations in the same test.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the tests wrong. The entire test, variable setup and all, MUST BE INSIDE the `it` functions.

What the `it` functions do is just push your tests to a list that will be executed either by the `describe` function or by mocha itself. The `it` functions do NOT execute the tests.

The correct way to write your test is as follows:

```
describe("Testing i", function(){

    it('i should be 0', function() {
        var i = 0;
        expect(i).to.equal(0);
    });

    it('i should be 1', function() {
        var i = 0;
        i++;
        expect(i).to.equal(1);
    });

    it('i should be 7', function() {
        var i = 0;
        i = 7;
        expect(i).to.equal(7);
    });
});
```

FWIW. All tests are executed synchronously unless you pass an argument into the callback of the `it` function. It's just that they're not executed inside the `describe` function. The `it` functions just compiles all your `it` calls into a list of tests.

Therefore, if you need to do a series of operations you can do this:

```
describe("Testing i", function(){
    var i;

    it('i should be 0', function() {
        i = 0;
        expect(i).to.equal(0);
    });

    it('i should be 1', function() {
        i++;
        expect(i).to.equal(1);
    });

    it('i should be 7', function() {
        i = 7;
        expect(i).to.equal(7);
    });
});
```

Note however that this is not recommended because if the first test fails then some of the following tests may fail as well. In this example, if the first test fails because the value of `i` is not 0 the second test will fail too. However, this pattern may be useful for steps that take a long time to execute (website login for example).

---

#### Why do it this way?

This allows mocha to do fancy test reporting like progress bars etc. Without knowing how many tests there are to run (a test is an `it` function), mocha cannot know what percentage to draw the progress bar.

It also allows mocha to do fancy formatting of error messages. If you've used mocha, you'll notice that mocha collects all error messages (fails) and print them at the end. To do that what mocha does is execute the tests (`it` functions) one at a time in a controlled manner and collecting any errors thrown. That's not possible if you rely on javascript syntax alone unless you hack the interpreter in C. But you can do that if you have a list of functions inside an array and execute them one function at a time.

Comment: I needs to do a series of tests after each other. I can do multiple expects in an it, but how can I inform mocha what each expect does? I'm doing some testing with synchronous event handling.

Comment: Each `it` will be called synchronously after each other. Just move all your code inside `it` blocks and they will work. It is not recommended though as one failing test will cause all following tests to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Answering to question, how the execution flow works.
Mocha starts with describe block.

In describe block first of all it executes all the code that is not in the `it` block.

So in your code first of all these 3 statements are executed before executing `it` blocks

```
var i = 0;
  i++;
  i=7;
```

Last value assigned to i is 7.
Now it will start executing it blocks.

Answer (score 1):

**A Solution like on the Mocha Documentation** https://mochajs.org/

```
describe("Testing i", function(){

    var i;
    it('i should be 0', function() {
        i = 0;
        expect(i).to.equal(0);
    });


    it('i should be 1', function() {
        i++;
        expect(i).to.equal(1);
    });

    it('i should be 7', function() {
        i= 7;
        expect(i).to.equal(7);
    });
});
```

**The calling order, as asked in the Question**
I tested it with a adapted code from this article http://cwinters.com/2014/09/26/mocha-nested-hook-ordering.html

Here is the code, I used

```
'use strict';

describe('level 1', function() {
  before(function() { console.log("L1 - before") });
  beforeEach(function() { console.log("L1 - beforeEach") });
  after(function() { console.log("L1 - after") });
  afterEach(function() { console.log("L1 - afterEach") });

console.log("inner DESCRIBE BEFORE L1A")  // equivalent to asigning the variable the first time
  it('L1 test A', function() {});
 console.log("inner DESCRIBE BEFORE L1B") // equivalent to asigning the variable the second time
  it('L1 test B', function() {});

  describe('level 2', function() {
    before(function() { console.log("L2 - before") });
    beforeEach(function() { console.log("L2 - beforeEach") });
    after(function() { console.log("L2 - after") });
    afterEach(function() { console.log("L2 - afterEach") });

    it('L2 test A', function() {});
    it('L2 test B', function() {});
  });
});
```

here the result

```
inner DESCRIBE BEFORE L1A     // execute First
inner DESCRIBE BEFORE L1B     // execute Second


  level 1                     // now the test are executed
L1 - before
L1 - beforeEach
    √ L1 test A
L1 - afterEach
L1 - beforeEach
    √ L1 test B
L1 - afterEach
    level 2
L2 - before
L1 - beforeEach
L2 - beforeEach
      √ L2 test A
L2 - afterEach
L1 - afterEach
L1 - beforeEach
L2 - beforeEach
      √ L2 test B
L2 - afterEach
L1 - afterEach
L2 - after
L1 - after


4 passing (64ms)
```

=> The `describe` Block will be execute immediately, so multiple variable asignment to the same varible will be overriden by the last one, before any other function is called. 
The first two test Fail because `i==7` when all three tests are executed.

*If the sequence is really needed you could use closure , but this would add a lot more complexity*.

Comment: Are you sure the solution is multiple it's? I'm getting the feeling that the solution might be multiple expects. But I'm not sure...

Comment: It depends on the assert / expects. In general, a unit test should test only one "thing". If this "one thing" has to be tested with various asserts/expects, multiple asserts/expects are vaild/the way to go. If there are different units, spliting it up would be the better choise. Althought, I would try to setup  (Enviroment for) the Test in the `beforeEach` part, if possible, to avoid mixup's

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: One `it` is one feature to test. Each feature or functionality may require multiple things to be asserted. So it depends. If your multiple `it` is merely testing ONE feature then combine them into a single `it`. If your single `it` is testing two features then split it. The key is to read the test as an english sentence: `it should do what` then add syntax: `it('should do what',function(){})`. If you can describe `it` as a feature, functionality, edge-case or bug then `it` should be a separate `it`