# What is the purpose of Mocha's #beforeEach when you can just run code inside the #describe scope?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, tdd, mocha.js

I'm learning TDD from this [article](http://thereignn.ghost.io/a-step-by-step-tdd-approach-on-testing-react-components-using-enzyme/) and the author talks about how Mocha's `beforeEach` will run a code before each assertion for you. But I don't understand why you need to do that when you can just run the code in the describe scope.

```
describe('Test suite for UserComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Prevent duplication
    wrapper = shallow(<UserComponent
                            name={ 'Reign' }
                            age={ 26 } />);
  });

  it('UserComponent should exist', () => {
    expect(wrapper).to.exist;
  });

  it('Correctly displays the user name and age in paragraphs wrapped under a parent div', () => {
    expect(wrapper.type()).to.equal('div');
    // more code...
  });
});
```

But not using the `beforeEach` would still work -

```
describe('Test suite for UserComponent', () => {

wrapper = shallow(<UserComponent
                        name={ 'Reign' }
                        age={ 26 } />);

  it('UserComponent should exist', () => {
    expect(wrapper).to.exist;
  });

  it('Correctly displays the user name and age in paragraphs wrapped under a parent div', () => {
    expect(wrapper.type()).to.equal('div');
    // more code...
  });
});
```

Comment: If you want to call ajax request before each test? or db request? or clear variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beforeEach` is executed before *each* test. This iteration is lost when the code is moved from `beforeEach` to be directly inside the function passed to `describe`. However, that's not all.

**In *some* cases, code executed directly inside the function passed to `describe` *can* perform the same task as a `beforeEach` hook.** For instance, if its function is to initialize a read-only structure that is local to the test in the `describe` block, then you could skip the `beforeEach` hook.

However, Mocha executes right away all the callbacks that are passed to `describe` calls whereas a `beforeEach` call registers the function passed to it *for future execution*, and it will be executed *only if needed*. If the initialization is expensive it is better to use a `beforeEach` hook because if you make use of `--grep` to select only some test, or use `it.only` to run a single test, then Mocha will run the hook only if it pertains to the test it will actually run. **If you have the initialization code in `describe`, Mocha cannot skip it so you'll pay the initialization cost *every time*.** However, if you are going to use a hook and the data is immutable, then `before` is better than `beforeEach` because it will run just *once* instead of before each test.

**Then there are cases where running code in directly in the function passed to `describe` simply won't work.** Imagine in the following that `sharedResource` is a resource that all tests need to use. It could be a third-party library that carries state, for instance. Some tests need it to be set to a certain state. Other tests need it to be in a different state. This does not work:

```
"use strict";

const assert = require('assert');

let sharedResource;

describe("in condition a", () => {
    sharedResource = true;

    it("sharedResource is true", () => assert(sharedResource));
});

describe("in condition b", () => {
    sharedResource = false;

    it("sharedResource is false", () => assert(!sharedResource));
});
```

The first test will fail because the execution order of the key statements is:

1. `sharedResource = true;`
2. `sharedResource = false;`
3. `assert(sharedResource);`
4. `assert(!sharedResource);`

The problem can be easily fixed by using `beforeEach`. This runs fine:

```
"use strict";

const assert = require('assert');

let sharedResource;

describe("in condition a", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        sharedResource = true;
    });

    it("sharedResource is true", () => assert(sharedResource));
});

describe("in condition b", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        sharedResource = false;
    });

    it("sharedResource is false", () => assert(!sharedResource));
});
```

Comment: I understand why the first test will fail but why would sharedResource be set to false when it's not in the scope of the first test? it comes afterwards and is set to false only in the 2nd test's scope so shouldn't it only apply to the 2nd test?

Comment: As I wrote "Mocha executes right away all the callbacks that are passed to describe calls". I did mention that `beforeEach` registers the hook for future execution but did not explicitly say that it is also the case for `it`. When Mocha executes `it`, the test is just recorded for future execution, it is not executed right away.  This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21470373/1906307) goes into the details of execution order.